# Why readline() input-echoing in console?

Tags: objective-c, c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char* input = readline(NULL);
    NSLog(@"%d", atoi(input));

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to enter a sequence of characters in console, but whenever I typed the one key, the same char will following immediately after the char which I just typed. (For example, I typed '1' in console, the console will display "11") Moreover, when I try to delete the entered char using delete-key. The up-side-down question mark will appear, but inside the char* the last char has been deleted?

Why all these happened?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UheQt.png]

Comment: Might be some problem with both `readline` and the console echoing?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How to fix this issue? I am following the textbook, it seems does not have any issue about this.

Comment: I think @JoachimPileborg is on the right track. If you run your program from Terminal, this problem does not occur. Try it by opening a new Terminal window and dragging the CountDown product (under the Products group in the Xcode navigator) into the terminal window. This will copy the path of your program into the Terminal prompt. Now if you run the program from the Terminal, the double input-echoing will not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior as of Xcode 5. You can run it outside Xcode in the terminal and it should behave normally.